# Condition on $(A,B,C,D)$ for functional to be inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Suppose a linear vector space $\mathbb{V}$ that has a two-dimensional column matrix as vector.
$$|u\rangle \rightarrow \ (x\ \ \ \ \  y)^T$$
Suppose the dual space  of  $\ \mathbb{V}$ have row vectors so that
$$\langle u|\ \rightarrow \ \ (Ax+By\ \ \ \ Cx+Dy)$$
Now suppose a linear map $\mathcal{L}: \mathbb{V}\rightarrow \ \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$(Ax+By\ \ \ Cx+Dy)\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y 
\end{pmatrix} =Ax^2+Dy^2+(B+C)xy$$
I want to find out the values or constraint on values of  $A, B, C, D$ such that this linear map represent an inner product on $\mathbb{V}$.

---

So far, I have taken specific values of $x,y$ to show that $A,B$ should be positive. For example :

$$\langle u|u\rangle =A(1)^2+D(0)^2+(B+C)(1)(0)=A>0$$
Similarly, $B>0$. Further If you take, $x=y=1$.
$$A+D+B+C>0$$
and $x=1=-y$
$$A+D-(B+C)>0\rightarrow -(A+D)<B+C<A+D$$
What I can do now? Any help is appreciable.

Comment: You're essentially asking when $\langle u\mid v\rangle:=u^TMv$  with $M=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}$ is an inner product. Does that help you?

Comment: Yeah, I see that $M$ is working as a metric in space. So I think, I'm looking for constraint on element of metric.

Comment: It's easier to think of it in terms of constraints on the matrix $M$ itself, instead of constraints on its elements. The matrix needs to be symmetric and positive definite. If you really want to get a constraint on its elements: Symmetry implies $C=B$ and positive definiteness means that the principal minors are all positive, meaning that $A$ is positive and $\det M$ is also positive. So the matrix is of the form $\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\B&D\end{pmatrix}$ with $A>0$ and $AD>B^2$.

Comment: How did you say that matrix needs to be symmetric and positive definite? And what symmetry implies that  $C=B$?

Comment: If $u^TMv$ is an inner product, then $u^TMv=v^TMu$. Also, since $u^TMv$ is just a number, it's the same as $(u^TMv)^T$, which in turn is just $v^TM^Tu$. So in the end we get that $v^TMu=v^TM^Tu$ for all $u$ and $v$, which is only possible if $M=M^T$. So $M$ is symmetric. In particular, its off-diagonal entries are equal. And if $u^TMv$ is an inner product, then in particular $u^TMu>0$ for all $u\neq0$. So $M$ is positive definite.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a bunch